# How do I remove the beginning elements of my array only if the first element satisfies a condition?

Tags: arrays, ruby, remove-if

In Ruby, let's say I have an array of ordreed, unique numbers

```
[0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

If the first element of the array is zero, how do I remove all the elements from teh beginning of the array that are consecutive, starting wiht zero?  That is, in the above example, I would want to remove "0", "1", and "2" leaving me with

```
[4, 6, 8, 10]
```

But if my array is

```
[1, 2, 3, 10, 15]
```

I would expect the array to be unchanged because the first element is not zero.

Comment: you want to remove the first 3 elements if the array starts with 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to delete entities if they match their idx (provided the first idx is 0). Try this:

```
   if array.first == 0 
      new_array = array.reject.each_with_index{ |item, idx| item == idx } 
  end
```

Although this will only work with ordered arrays of unique numbers, if you're not sure that they are then include: `array = array.sort.uniq`

Comment: True, but that isn't an ordered array which OP specified it would be. Also, in my edit I indicated that you can fix any array with `array.sort.uniq`

Answer (score 5):

You could use a mix of [`drop_while`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-drop_while) and [`with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) to only remove the first matching elements:

```
[0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10].drop_while.with_index{|x, i| x == i}
# [4, 6, 8, 10]

[1, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10].drop_while.with_index{|x, i| x == i}
# [1, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Note that the second and third elements don't get deleted in the second example, even though they're equal to their indices.

Answer (score 3):

Drop elements, as long as they are equal to their index:

```
a=a.drop_while.with_index{|e,i| e==i}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
x = -1
while my_array.first == x + 1 do
  x = my_array.shift
end
```

Note that array.shift is the same as array.pop except that it works from the start of the array.

Comment: Nice. It feels a bit like FORTRAN, but it was the first correct answer here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, then it can be one of possible solutions:

```
def foo(array)
  if array.first.zero?
    array.keep_if.with_index { |e, ind| e != ind }
  else
    array
  end
end

> foo([0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7])
#=> => [5, 6, 7]
> foo([1, 2, 3])
#=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score -1):

In short form:

```
a[0] == 0 ? a[3..-1] : a
```

In longer form:

```
if a.first == 0
  a[3..(a.size)]
else
  a
end
```

Comment: Not just "three elements". As many elements as they are consecutives